# How to process multilevel sources in akka asynchronously

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I have a list of list which i am looking forward to run it using akka and would want to do a operation when all of the child lists are done processing. But the Complete is running before all child's are completed.

Basically i am trying to read all the sheets in the excel and then read each rows from the excel. For this i am looking to use akka to process each sheets seperately and also in each sheet i am looking to process each rows seperately.

Sample Code:

```
    List<List<String>> workbook = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> Sheet1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    Sheet1.add("S");
    Sheet1.add("a");
    Sheet1.add("d");

    List<String> Sheet2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    Sheet2.add("S");
    Sheet2.add("a1");
    Sheet2.add("d");

    workbook.add(Sheet1);
    workbook.add(Sheet2);

    final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Sys");

    final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    Source.from(workbook).map(sheet -> {
        return Source.from(sheet).runWith(Sink.foreach(data -> {
            System.out.println(data);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }), materializer).toCompletableFuture();
    }).runWith(Sink.ignore(), materializer).whenComplete((a, b) -> {
        System.out.println("Complete");
    });
    system.terminate();
```

The Current output is:

```
S
S
Complete
a
a1
d
d
```

The Expected output is:

```
S
S
a
a1
d
d
Complete
```

Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a "stream within a stream" may be overcomplicating the process.

You could instead use [`Flow.flatMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/index.html?akka/stream/package-summary.html&_ga=2.24879550.524541850.1515330117-896188267.1511222114).  I can only provide an example in scala but hopefully it translates easily to java:

```
val flattenFlow : Flow[List[String], String, NotUsed] = 
  Flow[List[String].flatMapConcat(sheet => Source(sheet))

val Source[String] flattenedSource = Source(worksheet).via(flattenFlow)
```

There is [a blog post](https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-08-18-introduction-to-reactive-streams-for-java-developers/index.html) with a example of using `flatMapConcat` in java but I don't know if my guessed type `Flow.of(List<String>.class)` is valid code.